# div disappears in mobile view

Tags: html, css

So, I am new to responsive design and placed Form code on top of one image and it will not display in mobile view. It appears to happen around 990px wide that the form will go out of vision. I can't identify where the @media or what CSS class would hide the form after it goes to a certain width.

URL: subscribe.ign.com/social

```html
   <div class="site-slider">
                <div class="slider">
                    <div class="flexslider">
                        <ul class="slides">
                            <li>
                                <div class="overlay"></div>
                                <img src="http://static.ziffdavis.com.s3.amazonaws.com/cimages/blackfriday/Black-Friday-Email-Landing-Pages/black-friday-chaos-store-1600x750.png" alt="">
                                <div class="slider-caption visible-md visible-lg">
                              <div id="bouncex" align="center" style="width:558px; margin: 0 auto; ">
                              
                              <!--LYRIS-->
                              <div class="heading-section col-md-12 text-center">
                        <div class="contact-form" style="background-color:#000 !important; padding: 25px">
                        <h2 style="text-transform:capitalize; font-size:34px">BLACK FRIDAY IS COMING</h2>
                        <br/>
                        <p style="text-transform:capitalize; font-size:28px">UP TO 50% OFF</p>
                        <h2 style="text-transform:capitalize; font-size:24px">ON HOTTEST GAMES AND TECH DEALS DELIVERED TO YOUR INBOX</h2>
                            <form name="contactform" id="contactform">
                               <p><input name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" type="text" placeholder="Your Email"> 
                                </p>
                                 <input type="button" class="mainBtn" name="btnSubscribe" id="btnSubscribe" value="Subscribe">
                                 <input type="hidden" name="txtList" id="txtList" size="70" value="ign-deals" />
                                 <p style="color:#FFF;font-size:14px">Subscribing to a newsletter indicates your consent <br/>to our&nbsp;<a style="color:#d3222a; text-decoration:underline" href="http://www.ziffdavis.com/terms-of-use" title="Terms of Use" rel="nofollow">User Agreement</a>&nbsp;and&nbsp;<a style="color:#d3222a; text-decoration:underline" href="http://www.ziffdavis.com/privacy-policy" title="Privacy Policy" rel="nofollow">Privacy Policy</a><span id="article-punctuation" class="article-punctuation">
                                    
                                </span></p>
                            </form>
                        </div> <!-- /.contact-form -->
                    </div> <!-- END LYRIS -->
                              </div>
                                  </div>
                                    
                               
                            </li>
                           
                        </ul>
                    </div> <!-- /.flexslider -->
                </div> <!-- /.slider -->
            </div> <!-- /.site-slider -->
```

Comment: please post the css here

Answer (score 0):

just set :

```
<ul class="slides" style="list-style:none; padding-left: 0;">

<img style="width: 100%; " src="your url" alt="">
```

**Try it now :** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOJEaw

Answer (score 0):

Your div with `slider-caption`class also has `visible-md visible-lg`, you should remove this 2 classes. Basically, it makes that div visible only on screens with 992px width or bigger.

You can learn more about it on [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

Answer (score 0):

The **reason** it is 'disappearing' is because of the parent element: `<div class="slider-caption visible-md visible-lg">`.

It is getting `display: none !important;` at `992px` which is a [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) breakpoint. Specifically though it is the `visible-*` class that is doing it. [Read about that in the Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).